# Docker - swarm with docker toolbox doesn't run

Tags: docker

i applied docker tutorial to set up a swarm.
I used docker toolbox, because i'm on windows 10 Family.

i step all statements, but at the end, the statement "curl ip_adress" doesn't run. error also with access on url.

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24302
```

docker-compose.yml, located in /home/docker of virtual machine called "myvm1" :

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    # replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
    image: 12081981/friendlyhello:part1
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

swarm :

```
$ docker-machine ssh myvm1 "docker stack ps getstartedlab"
ID                  NAME                  IMAGE                          NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE           ERROR               PORTS
blmx8mldam52        getstartedlab_web.1   12081981/friendlyhello:part1   myvm1               Running             Running 9 seconds ago
04ctl86chp6o        getstartedlab_web.2   12081981/friendlyhello:part1   myvm3               Running             Running 6 seconds ago
r3qyznllno9j        getstartedlab_web.3   12081981/friendlyhello:part1   myvm3               Running             Running 6 seconds ago
2twwicjssie9        getstartedlab_web.4   12081981/friendlyhello:part1   myvm1               Running             Running 9 seconds ago
o4rk4x7bb3vm        getstartedlab_web.5   12081981/friendlyhello:part1   myvm3               Running             Running 6 seconds ago
```

result of "docker-machine ls" :

```
    NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER     ERRORS
default   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v18.09.0
myvm1     *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.102:2376           v18.09.0
myvm3     -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.103:2376           v18.09.0
```

test with curl

```
$ curl 192.168.99.102
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.99.102 port 80: Connection refused
```

How do i do to debug ?

I can give more information, if you want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is your service defined? Did you publish a port and is the application listening on a port?

Comment: I'm going to add to the original message, the contents of docker-compose.yml

Comment: I added to the original message, the contents of docker-compose.yml now.
I publish on port 80 and application listen on port 80.

Comment: Add the output of `docker run -it --rm --net container:$container_id nicolaka/netshoot ss -lnt` where $container_id is from one of your containers.

Comment: it pulls the image, and at the end :

`C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"ss-lnt\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.`

Comment: There should be a space between `ss` and args `-lnt`, it's the newer version of `netstat -lnt`.

Comment: sorry. i executed again the command. the result : 
`$ docker run -it --rm --net container:dc7741b4d9f0 nicolaka/netshoot ss -lnt

State    Recv-Q    Send-Q        Local Address:Port        Peer Address:Port


LISTEN   0         0                127.0.0.11:36745            0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN   0         0                   0.0.0.0:80               0.0.0.0:*`

Comment: Everything looks right to me from the docker and app side, best guess is that it's a windows/VM issue. I'm guessing if you `docker-machine ssh myvm1 "curl http://localhost"` it would work.

Comment: thanks for your help.  
it doesn't work !  
`$ docker-machine ssh myvm1 "curl http://localhost"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
exit status 7`

it's the same with `curl http://192.168.99.102`

Comment: That rules out the VM. On the windows side, there are some reported issues with ingress networking not working. Not sure if that includes the docker-machine variants, or if/when they fixed it. Here's an issue to follow: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1109

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of the routing mesh in Windows appears to be an EE only feature right now. You can monitor [this docker for windows issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1109) for more details. The current workaround is to use DNSRR internally and publish ports to the host directly instead of with the routing mesh. If you want your application to be reachable from any node in the cluster, this means you'd need to have a service on ever host in the cluster, scheduled globally, listening on the requested port. E.g.

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  web:
    # replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
    image: 12081981/friendlyhello:part1
    deploy:
      # global runs 1 on every node, instead of the replicated variant
      mode: global
      # DNSRR skips the VIP normally assigned to services
      endpoint_mode: dnsrr
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        protocol: tcp
        # host publishes the port directly from the container without the routing mesh
        mode: host
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  
It runs !  
i teared down the app and the swarm, used your new docker-compose.yml

`docker-machine ssh myvm1 "curl ip_address"` : OK with 192.168.99.102, 192.168.99.103, localhost. 

with web browser, it's ok but not for http://localhost.  
For the tutorial "container", it runs for 192.168.99.102, not for localhost.

i wonder why the curl command ran with localhost

Comment: Localhost might work with an ssh, otherwise your vm's are different from localhost.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I read issue that you have quoted. I'm going to continue docker tutorials. I hope that i haven't others problems, cause by docker toolbox version.

Comment: i didn't find to get 5 instances (subtitute "replica" option). Have you an idea please ?

Comment: From the comment in the file above: "global runs 1 on every node, instead of the replicated variant"

Comment: ok, however, if i want 5 instances, i set in docker-compose.yml, "replicas: 5" and i delete "mode: global" ?

Comment: For any service publishing a port in mode host, to replace the mesh networking concept, you want it keep it globally scheduled, one instance per node. Otherwise you have containers failing to start because the port is in use, or some nodes not publishing the port because no container is running there. The best case would be the same number of replicas per nodes, but that doesn't handle failures or new nodes gracefully.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm not sure to understand everything. With docker CE, i mustn't use replicas, et create 5 vm instead of 5 replicas.